# I want to parse multiple strings into variables from a .txt file in java. What's the easiest way to do it?

Tags: java, string, file, parsing

What's the best way to do it? Should I use the File class and scanner? I've never done it before and can't seem to find a solid guide for it online so I figured I would ask here.

Edit:
The text file I am parsing is 3 columns, the first three are ID NAME BIRTHDATE then actual data.

Edit (code from [pastie](http://pastie.org/1051615)):

```
public void readFromFile(File file ) 
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("success..");
        s = new Scanner(file);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String jj = null;
        while((jj = input.readLine())!=null)
        {  
            String [] words = jj.split("\\t");
            String name = "";
            String id = "";
            String birthdate ="";
            for (int i = 3; i<words.length; i+=3)
            {
                id =words[i];
                name = words[i+1];
                birthdate=words[i+2];
                Person p = new Person(id, name, birthdate);
                peopleMap.put(p.id,p);
                names.add(p);
                System.out.println("New entry added to file: "+name+"\\t"+"ID: "
                                    +id+"\\t"+"Birthdate"+birthdate);
            }
        }
    }

    catch(IOException e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: http://pastie.org/1051615 

is my code so far.. seemingly not able to create new Persons

Comment: The text file I am parsing is 3 columns, the first three are ID NAME BIRTHDATE then actual data. I think my parsing is correct, I did lots of testing with prints.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way depends on the format of the text file. From your other comment, it sounds like the lines are tab separated values. As a beginner you will probably find it simplest to use Scanner. Specifically, Scanner.nextLine(). Couple that with using String.split("\t") to split the data into an array (assuming the format is tab-separated-values).

Comment: Thanks, I will see what I can come up with.

Comment: http://pastie.org/1051615 Here is where I am at.

I am having problems getting the "new person added to file" sysout.
PeopleMap is my treeMap, and names is my arrayList. They already contain some values, that part works fine.

Comment: @Cody, sorry. Your comment is not really StackOverflow friendly. If you have additional questions or need to post clarifications (such as the input format or a code snippet) you should edit the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Simply depends on the format of the text file.

1. If its simple name value pair then you can use java.util.Properties. for example a.properties could look like:

   ```
   name=john
   city=san jose
   date=12 july 2010
   ```

then you can load this as:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream("a.properties"));
```

2. If format is different than what is supported by java.util.Properties.load() then using java.util.Scanner would be helpful to process it line by line:

   ```
   File file = new File("data.txt");
   try 
   {
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
       while (scanner.hasNextLine()) 
       {
           String line = scanner.nextLine();
           //Process each line seperately
           processLine(line);
       }
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

Comment: http://pastie.org/1051615 Here is my code so far, I am having troubles getting it to print the new entry t console msg. Any ideas? I used File.

Answer (score 1):

If you are free to say what the syntax / structure of the text file is, then consider making it a Java properties file.  Then you can load and save the file with minimal programming effort using the [`java.util.Properties`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class.

Comment: it is in 3 columns, with sample Name, ID, and birthrate variables. I'll take a look at the properties class on the api but I think my Lab is encouraging me to use File and scanner and Print Writer.

Comment: @Cody - properties file format is not applicable to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I like to do in that situation:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
Scanner line;
String name;
String date;
int id;
while(s.hasNext()){
   line = new Scanner(s.nextLine());
   id = line.nextInt();
   name = line.next/*String*/();
   date = line.next/*String*/();
   /* Do something with id, name and date */
}
```

*Maybe there is some exception handling or something like that*

(Anyone want to comment on the efficiency of creating many new Scanners?)

Comment: Well... creating the extra Scanner is entirely unnecessary since you could simply call `nextInt(), next(), next()` on the original.  
Also, what if someone had a two-part name like "Jim Bob"? Using `next()` doesn't really handle that situation.